# Is there something wrong in my program that prints the characters for the ASCII CODE?

Tags: c, ascii

Is there something wrong with my program that prints the characters for the ASCII Code?
My program doesn't print characters from 0 to 32. Otherwise, it works.

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    
    for(i=0; i<=127; i++){
        if(i%10 == 0){
            printf("--------------------\n");
            printf(" Dec  Char \n");
            printf("--------------------\n");
            
        }
        printf(" %d %5c \n", i, i);
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: The "characters" from 0 to 32 are not printable, they are control codes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart

Comment: "Is there something wrong in my program that prints the characters for the ASCII CODE?" --> No.  "My program don't print characters from 0 to 32." is in incorrect conclusion.  Try "piping" your results to a file `prog > ouput.txt` and then look at the length of the file.  Was it as expected?

Comment: Please share more details - what had you expected?

Answer (score 5):

> My program don't print characters from 0 to 32.

Your program does print all characters from 0 to 127, inclusive. Presuming your C implementation uses ASCII, which is likely, most of the characters from 0 to 32 and character 127 do not have entirely visible effects.

The characters from 0 to 31 are control codes of various kinds. Character 7 is an “alert” character. You likely heard a ding, beep, or other sound when it was “printed.”

Character 9 is a horizontal tab. If you print a visible character before it and another after it, you will see some amount of space between them. The space will be such that the character after it is printed in the text “tab column,” often column 8, 16, 24, 32, and so on with default settings (counting the first column as column 0).

Character 10 is a line-feed or new-line character, which moved the paper up in old teletype machines. You probably saw a blank line after “10” and before “11” due to this character. 13 is a carriage return. (Originally it moved the carriage, the mechanism holding the paper, back to align the left side with the printing mechanism. Later, it moved the printing mechanism back to the left side of the paper.) 12 is a vertical tab. 8 is a backspace. In modern terminal window software, printing “a”, backspace, and “b” would likely backspace over the “a” and replace it with “b”. In old teletypes, it would physically print the “b” over the “a”.

32 is a space. It was printed normally, but your output does not give a clear way to make it visible. (It could be visible by copying the text from the terminal window, pasting it into a text editor, and examining the specific characters in detail. That could reveal there is a space character in that line that is not present in the line above it.) If you print “a”, space (character 32), and “b”, you will see the space.

Character 127 is a delete character.

Many of the other codes are archaic for text output to humans. However, some of them have uses for input, such as signaling requests to pause or resume program output, to interrupt or to suspend a program, to undo the character most recently typed, and so on. In addition, the escape character, 27, is used to start “escape sequences” that some terminal software interprets as requests of various kinds, such as to change the text color, put new text in the window title bar, or to change or report the cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

You can print ascii after 32 these 32 for control like start text, end text etc.